# Python using exec with custom globals

Tags: python, shell, exec

I would like to create a simple python shell. So right now I am stuck on executing the code. The question is, is there a way to run `exec` with **custom globals**? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass custom global dictionary as follow:

```
a, b = 1, 2
exec('print(a+b)', {'a': 5, 'b': 5}) # prints 10
```

Reference: [The `exec` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement)